# Trouble isolating emails when downloading via Python script

Tags: python

I have a script that fetches emails from my account, downloads the attachments, creates some html for an email blast program, and then zips them into a nice little archive. This works well when only one email is present in the inbox, however, the script hangs when multiple emails exist. I feel like this is because the section of the script that zips the files is not looping correctly. What I am trying to accomplish is one zip file for each email. 3 emails in the inbox = 3 seperate zip files. I've done my best to reduce my code for maximum readability while still maintaining the core structure. Could anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

Code:

```
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            content = part.get_payload()
            #do something/define variables from email contents           

    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        counter = 1

        if not filename:
            filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, 'bin')
            counter += 1

        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

        if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()

    path = 'C:\directory'
    os.chdir(path)
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        #download attachments
    htmlFile = str(token)+'.html'
    htmlCode = ('<html>HTML goes here</html>')
    htmlData = open(os.path.join('C:\directory', htmlFile), 'w+')
    htmlData.write(htmlCode)
    print htmlFile+' Complete'
    htmlData.close()
    allFiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.')]
    for file in allFiles:
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(token+'.zip', mode='a')
        archive.write(file)
        archive.close()
        os.unlink(file)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is alink to the complete code. http://ideone.com/WEXv9P

Comment: I doubt they will see this, but whoever downvoted, could you please explain why? Not that the downvote is that big of a deal, I would just prefer to know what my mistake was so I don't repeat it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake here:

```
        counter = 1

    if not filename:
        filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, 'bin')
        counter += 1
```

Counter will always be 1 in this loop, you probably want to define it before the second

```
for part in mail.walk():
```

EDIT:

Okay, so I think the problem is at the last part of the code

```
    allFiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.')]
    for file in allFiles:
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(token+'.zip', mode='a')
        archive.write(file)
        archive.close()
        os.unlink(file)
```

this will create a zip file for each part of the email

I think what you want to do is indent this out a level and change it to something more like this:

```
allFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(detach_dir) if not f.endswith(".zip")]
for file in allFiles:
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(token+'.zip', mode='a')
    archive.write(file)
    archive.close()
    os.unlink(file)
```

That way it won't recursively zip other zip files or remove them

Comment: Thanks, but it's still hanging on me

Comment: Might need you to post some more code, does the `token` variable change somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the `token` variable is parsed from the email content. I've updated my question above with a link to the entire code

Comment: Alright, added an edit with what I think might be the problem.